# Transform broadcast packet to unicast

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, iptables

DHCP requests are broadcast messages. I need to redirect it to a particular IP address so that I can test a new DHCP server. Is it possible using IPTables?

Comment: It makes no sense to "redirect" broadcasts, and you can't test the DHCP server properly if it doesn't act on broadcasts. Make some network namespaces with veth-pairs (and bridge them, if you need to), let the DHCP client broadcast on this (virtual) LAN segement, let the DHCP server listen to it. Easy testing without additional hardware.

Comment: You are basically asking to create a new vlan which I can't afford now.

Comment: No, I am not asking to create a new VLAN - veth pairs have nothing to do with VLAN. Please edit your question and add details: What is/are the DHCP client, where is the DHCP server, why do you think you can test the DHCP server only in this particular way?